# Positive integers greater than 79 that are the sum of fourth powers of 19 positive integers.(minimum 19 terms)

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics

I know that numbers till 79 can be expressed as a sum of fourth powers of 18 positive integers and 79 is the smallest number to require 19 terms.

What are some other numbers that require a minimum of 19 terms? Repetition is allowed

Comment: You either mean "$18$ nonnegative integers" or "no more than $18$ positive integers."  But in either event, I don't understand the question.  What about $3^4=81?$

Comment: @saulspatz he is asking about $g(4)$ in Waring's problem.

Comment: @WillJagy Yes, I realize that, but read the last sentence again.  "There is no number greater than $79$ that can be expressed as a sum of $18$ fourth powers ..." Huh?

Comment: Actually, what I meant what are some numbers that need 19 terms other than 79, that is numbers larger than 79 that cannot be expressed as sum of 18 terms but require 19 terms

Comment: @saulspatz agreed, not well written. Apparently there is a brief summmary by Deshoulliers talking about the use of the circle method in proving $g(4) = 19$ Since I have a book on the circle method, maybe it has an answer (is the quoted 79 the only number needing 19 quartics, or are there larger ones?)

Comment: @WillJagy, ya that is what I need numbers greater than 79 for which we need a minimum 19 terms

Comment: Ankit, I have found some of the relevant articles by Deshouillers and others. I'm not sure what type of article would have your information.  https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/6eb3/777dcf4ca565cfd766ab98c7c20d4c1e35a1.pdf

Comment: @WillJagy Thanks, all I am looking for is numbers like 79 (minimum 19 terms), I am totally lost here

Comment: Why are you looking for this????

Comment: @WillJagy, I came across a problem in the exercise and i have no idea how to go about it

Comment: I suggest you move on to some other problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a snippet from "Waring's Problem" by P.M. Batchelder, in the *Monthly,* Vol. $43,$ No. $1$ (January $1936$) listing $6$ other numbers that require $19$ fourth powers.  Of course, nowadays it is known that $g(4)=19.$

[image]

I wonder if the largest integer requiring $19$ fourth powers is known.  [YES](http://www.numdam.org/issue/MSMF_2005_2_100__1_0.pdf)

Comment: Good. I really couldn't find anything that had specific numbers in it.

Comment: @Saul thanks a lot. I don't think it is possible to determine the largest number in this case.

Comment: @AnkitSingh it is https://oeis.org/A046050  "Deshouillers, Hennecart and Landreau showed that this sequence is complete up to 10^245, and Kawada, Wooley and Deshouillers showed that it is complete beyond 10^220."

Comment: Wow, that was helpful, trying to find that proof that the sequence is complete up to 10^245, maybe that will enable to compute more such numbers that require 19 terms

Comment: @AnkitSingh Click on the link that Will Jagy at the end of my answer.  (The one that says "YES".)  It also proves that every number greater than $13792$ can be written as a sum of not more that $16$ fourth powers, as a consequence.

Answer (score 1):

Well:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{18}n^4=432345$$
that is $1^4+2^4+\cdots+18^4=432345$, which disproves your theory nicely.

---

For things requiring $19$ terms, we would have $$\sum_{n=1}^{19}n^4=562666$$

Fermat's Last Theorem (or some number-crunching) verifies that this can't be condensed into $18$ terms.

Furthermore, because Fermat's Last Theorem proves that a sum of $n$ fourth powers *cannot* be expressed as the sum of $n-1$ fourth powers (provided one of the powers isn't $0$), you can generate any list of $19$ non-zero fourth powers and their sum is certainly not expressible as the sum of $18$ fourth powers.

Comment: Which of the statements does it contradict?

Comment: Unless I'm mis-interpreting, the OP is suggesting that there is no integer greater than $79$ which can be written as the sum of eighteen fourth powers. This is contradicting that.

Comment: Well, the question is about the numbers that require at least 19 terms.

Comment: @Ryhs Hughes, no i am having trouble finding numbers that need 19 terms, i guess there might be some numbers that we an express as sum of more than 19 terms but the question is a number that cannot be expressed as sum of less than 19 terms like the number 79

Comment: @Ryan 562666 can be expressed as a sum of less than 19 fourth powers, my question is about the numbers that cannot be expressed as sum of less than 19 fourth power terms

Comment: @AnkitSingh, I don't believe it can be. Can you show me?

Comment: For example, 16 can be expressed as 1^4+1^4.....16 times but it can also be expressed as 2^4 , a single term or as 2^4+0^4.... any number of times. So, what I am looking for is a number that cannot be expressed in less than 19 terms like the number 79

Comment: You didn't show me for $562666$. You showed me for $16$. I don't believe there is a way to write $1^4+2^4+...+19^4=562666$ as anything less than $19$ fourth powers...